# How to fetch all entities which has createdAt parameter type Date by specific Month?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a class that has a parameter of type Date.

```
class MyEntity { 
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date createdAt;
}
```

How can I retrieve all those entities where the createdAt is i.e.: in May? Do I need to use @Query or is there a different way to perform it?

Comment: I am afraid @query only provides one with an method to create SQL queries, the question you raise is beyond this engine. You need to implement data filter logic either in SQL directly which probably not easiest way to do it or  at application level ( retrieving the data and doing filter by date ). In both way there is no out of the box solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to use @Query?

Yes )

> How can I retrieve all those entities where the createdAt is i.e.: in May?

If your JPA provider is Hibernate (I'm sure that it's so), you can use `month()` and [other useful HQL functions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-functions) in your queries:

```java
@Query("select e from MyEntry e where month(e.createdAt) = ?1")
List<MyEntry> getAllByMonth(int month);
```